# Как преобразовать массив байт в массив строк подгруженных из файла?

Tags: golang, текст

Только начинаю изучать Go перейдя с Python. Посмотрел код в Google и не нашел нормального пояснения к данному вопросу.  Сразу скажу, что знаю об I/O и просто обычном чтении побайтово из файла.

Вопрос: **Как считать строки из файла, сложив их в массив или вектор строкового типа?**

**Файл.txt** (не CSV):

```
1,pol\n
2,kjksk\n
3,01203103\n
```

Предполагаемый **вектор или массив**:

```
["1,pol", "2,kjksk", "3,01203103"]
```

*P.S.* Пожалуйста, скиньте полный код в виде функции или пакета.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на *StackOverflow*.  Мемы и прочие не относящиеся напрямую к вопросу картинки лучше не добавлять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner)
к структуре `Scanner` из пакета `bufio`
приводится пример, который легко модифицируется
под ваши нужды:

```golang
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("./file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    var lines []string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }

    err = scanner.Err()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", lines)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А что делает форматированный вывод?

Comment: Если вы про последнюю строчку, это просто для демонстрации результата.